# Why is createBufferStrategy(3) just as fast as createBufferStrategy(3+x)?

Tags: java, buffer, bufferstrategy

As far as I know, you can put any int into the createBufferStrategy parameter. I've been told that there's no visible difference in buffer speed after triple buffering.

Why is this?

Comment: maybe a look at the source code will help clarify this? in openJdk: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/awt/Component.java#Component.createBufferStrategy%28int%29

Comment: Think of it like a pool of buffers, one which is been painted to the screen, one which is been painted to and the rest waiting to be used, so unless you're doing some insane multiple frame painting through multiple threads, you're only going to have two "active buffers" with a third in reserve (in most cases)